# Spring MVC with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Are there any sample / tutorial on Spring MVC with JSP without using Tag Libraries. Pure JSP.
I am not conversant with Tag Libraries and I am good with JSP. So I would like to see if there are any examples and tutorials using pure JSP without ANY tag libraries.

Comment: What exactly is "Pure JSP"? JSTL/EL? Or oldschool *scriptlets*? Given that JSTL is also a tag library and that EL is not very useful without JSTL, I'll bet that you're still using oldschool *scriptlets*. Well, I certainly wouldn't consider putting Java code in a JSP file instead of a Java class "Pure JSP". That's just "Pure Bad Practice". On the other hand, a *scriptlet*-free JSP can be considered "Pure JSP".

Comment: `"Pure Bad Practice"` Lol! I get your point. Yes, I was referring to oldschool scriptlet without Tag library. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't mean to say this in a degrading manner, but if you are good with JSP, you should be able to pick up the Spring MVC tags easily. JSP, custom tags and ELs go hand-in-hand. They are created for a reason: to make your life simpler. A quick example, if you use Spring MVC's [form tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.form), Spring MVC will automatically prefill the form fields for you based on the data you have in the model. Think about how tedious your code will be to prefill the checkboxes/radiobuttons or preselect the drop down lists.

If you are also Spring Security, the [provided custom tags](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html) allow you to easily control what data to be displayed based on the user roles.

Writing all of that using pure JSP don't even make sense to me... not to mention the amount of time wasted writing less than perfect home grown solutions.

Comment: Sure, I get your point. But Well, anyways, I still wanted to see if there are any examples out there. Pure JSP meaning, scriptlet.. without taglibraries.

Comment: Even if there are examples out there, I myself wouldn't post them here. Take the time to learn the tags and do it the right way. As @BalusC said, it is indeed "pure bad practice" to embed Java code in JSP using scriplets. Sooner or later, your business logic and views are all jumbled in the same file. Then, what's the point of using Spring MVC in the first place?

Comment: Hmmm.. I have to agree. :-)